# "Trick" to demonstrate expression is a probability density function for the Gaussian Distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was looking into a particular method to demonstrate that the following expression is a probability density function for the Gaussian / Normal distribution. (i.e. that the integral = 1) :

$$ f_{X} (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( \frac{-(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) $$ 
 
Define $$ I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp \left( \frac{-(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) $$ 
If we take $ y = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \ \ $,$ \ \ \sigma \ dy = dx $, we need to show that:

$$ \sqrt{2\pi} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}} dy$$ 
$$ I_{1} (r) = \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{-r}^{r} e^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}} dy $$
This is where the "trick" is performed, to approximate a square $ [(-r,-r),(r,-r),(-r,r),(r,r)] \ $ using an inner (radius $r$) and outer circle (radius $\sqrt{2} r$). What I'm having difficult understanding is how we got the expression below for $ I_{1} (r)^{2} $, or in other words, how did we convert the above expression into a double integral. I can't visualize how the expression  $ e^\frac{-y^{2}}{2}$, with a Gaussian-looking curve can be"doubled" and then approximated by a square - **what is the reasoning behind this?**

Just to clarify what I'm saying and where this is headed - here is rest of the derivation.

$$ I_{1} (r)^{2} = \left( \int_{-r}^{r} e^\frac{-y^{2}}{2} dy \right) \left( \int_{-r}^{r} e^\frac{-x^{2}}{2} dx \right) $$

$$ = \int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r} e^\frac{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2} dx \ dy $$

$$ = \iint\limits_{x^{2} + y^{2} < r^{2} } e^\frac{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2} dx \ dy $$

$$ = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r} e^\frac{-r^{2}}{2} r \ dr \ \ r \ d\theta $$

$$ = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \big[ -e^\frac{-r^{2}}{2} \big]^{R}_{0} \ d\theta = 2 \pi \big[1- e^\frac{-R^{2}}{2} \big] $$

$$I_{2} (r) \leq I_{1}^{2} (r) \leq I_{2} (\sqrt{2} r) $$

$$ 2 \pi (1-e^\frac{-R^{2}}{2}) \leq I_{1}^{2} (r) \leq 2 \pi (1-e^\frac{-R^{2}}{2}) $$

$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} I_{1}^{2} = 2\pi $$ (via Squeeze Theorem)

$$ I_{1} = \sqrt{2\pi} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-y^{2}}{2} dy $$

Is there a more intuitive way to determine that the expression is a PDF for the Gaussian Distribution?

Comment: You confused things big time. No, $$\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r} e^\frac{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2} dx \ dy $$
is not
$$ = \iint\limits_{x^{2} + y^{2} < r^{2} } e^\frac{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2} dx \ dy. $$ By the by, what is this $I_2(r)$, never defined, which appears out of nowhere? Answering this might answer the whole.

Comment: This was from my professor's notes. I was slightly confused about the notation - I copied it verbatim assuming it was standard. I'm fairly sure the $I_{2}$ refers to the circle approximation, the parenthesis value denotes the radius of the approximating circle. $ I_{1} (r) $ means a r*r square. My textbook directly solves the double integral after using a change of variables to polar coordinates with $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, dy dx = r d\theta dr$. I wanted to understand the intuition behind this alternate method since directly resolving the integrals seems much cleaner.

Comment: No, $I_1(r)$ is the integral on a segment hence $I_1(r)^2$ is an integral on a square while $I_2(r)$ is *defined* as the integral on a disk. Of course the notation $I_2(r)$ is not standard, simply you omitted to copy its definition. "directly resolving the integrals seems much cleaner" You mean, directly computing $I_1(r)$? Please show how you propose to do that...

Comment: I meant computing $I_{1}^{2}$. 

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} e^{-y^{2}/2} dy \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/2} dx $$ 
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(y^{2} + x^{2})/2} dy dx $$ then performing the above mentioned change to polar coordinates to get:
$$ I_1^{2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^{2}/2}r d\theta dr $$
$$ = 2\pi \int_{0}^{-\infty} re^{-r^{2}/2} dr $$
$$ - 2\pi e^{-r^{2}/2} |_{0}^{\infty} $$
$$ = 2\pi $$

By 'standard', I meant $ I_{2} $ was used to denote approximations using circles.

Comment: Yeah, and the comparison of the integrals on squares and on disks is the standard way to make this approach rigorous.

Comment: Hmm, understood. The problem I'm having is trying to visually understand the 'square' we're trying to approximate here, what does it represent?  it feels inherently difficult since we're dealing with $\infty$.

Comment: No we are not "dealing with ∞", rather your professor explains precisely how to avoid using ∞ and you suggest to replace their approach by another one which forces one to "deal with ∞", whatever that means. If you find that "dealing with ∞" is problematic, just adopt your professor's approach. (Do you understand why the double inequality in your post is based on the fact that each square contains a specific disk and is contained in another specific disk?)

Comment: Thats not exactly what I meant, I meant taking $ lim_{r \to \infty} and then approximating a square with verticies [(-r,-r), ... , (r,r) ] which really leaves me confused about what a "square becoming arbritarily large" means in this case.

Comment: Sorry but one approximates nothing here, please reread what I (and your professor) wrote. It seems every precise point you raised is now addressed. The rest is difficult to understand (to wit, your last comment, which squarely contradicts some of your previous assertions), so, unless a real question emerges...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are prety clear here, your notations are the ones that confuse everything.

Let $I_1 (r) = \int \limits _{-r} ^r$ and $I_1 = \lim \limits _{r \to \infty} I_1 (r)$.

Let $D(r)$ be the disk of centerpoint $(0,0)$ and radius $r$. Let $I_2 (r) = \iint \limits _{D(r)}$ (in polar coordinates).

Now $I_1 ^2 = \left( \lim \limits _{r \to \infty} I_1 (r) \right) ^2 = \lim \limits _{r \to \infty} I_1 (r) ^2 = \lim \limits _{r \to \infty} I_2 (r)$ (even though $I_1 (r) ^2 \ne I_2 (r)$), so $I_1 = \sqrt {\lim \limits _{r \to \infty} I_2 (r)}$, and $I_2 (r)$ is really easy to compute.

In simpler words: to compute the integral on $\Bbb R ^2$ you may choose to view $\Bbb R^2$ either as a limit of increasing squares, or as a limit of increasing disks - the result will be the same. You use squares in order to obtain the square of the integral you desire; you use disks next in order to change to polar coordinates where it is easy to perform computations explicitly.

Comment: Ah, got it. Cleared the confusion about what the limits were doing.